# Selenium - Creating UI driven automation framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to create a framework for selenium testing. It should be a UI driven web framwork in which any user can test the AUT by just selecting desired module to be tested from a drop down and clicking on 'Test' button. Give some idea how such a framwork is developed. Preferred languauge is Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use POM(Page Object Model) :-

POM is a highly maintainable and flexible.

You can create each suite according to your requirement.

It is the highly recommended and POM framework used by most of the industries

Refer below:-
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/

Hope it will help you :)